# scala-spray: why do I get escaped strings with trailing quotes?

Tags: spray, spray-json

I'm new to scala and spray and I'm having a very simple problem.   I want my rest service to return unescaped strings when I return a string from a rest call, it stead i'm getting a compacted string with escapes in it.   Here is my code:

Rest Service:
....

```
get {
     respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`text/plain`) {
        complete {
                    s"""
hey joe this is 
"me" 
bill"""
          }
      }
   }
```

When I call the my service I get:

```
"\nhey joe this is\n\"me\"\n\bill"
```

But if I do a println() I see what I would expect.   Please help.

Comment: You don't need `respondWithMediaType`. Also, it does work for me as intended. How did you test?

Comment: I tested by using CURL and a normal webbrowser to call the service and it returns all the \t and \n in the string with the trailing quotes.  I'm trying to use the results in a non-program so having these escaped characters makes it unusable.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my own problem, it was the JSON support trait that was automatically marshalling the object

This trait **Json4sSupport** automatally marshal your objects as JSON hence the wrapping and compact print etc.

```
import spray.httpx.Json4sSupport
```

If you remove it you should be getting the unescaped results.

hope it helps anyone else out there.

Comment: Ah, cool you figured it out. Maybe we should even consider this a bug because a plain json string is not a valid json document.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem using Jackson; we worked around the issue by creating an http response object instead, like so…

```
              respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) {
                complete {
                  new HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, HttpEntity(
                    """
                    |<!DOCTYPE html>
                    |<html>
                    |<head>
                    |<title>Download app</title>
                    |</head>
                    |<body>
                    |<h2>
                    |Click <a href="/download/test.txt">here</a><br>
                    |</h2>
                    |</body>
                    |</html>
                  """.stripMargin
                  ))
                }
              }
```